# Spatial4j + solr4.1 = distance (radius) searches on polygons and linestrings?

Tags: solr, spatial

I have polygons and linestrings working but cant seem to get the format on applying a distance to those searches. Im trying to do a search say 100km within a linestring.
My queries look like this.

```
geo:"Intersects(LINESTRING(126.9140625 -17.644022027872722, 142.646484375 -20.46818922264095, 133.59375 -29.305561325527698, 127.0458984375 -18.62542454070125) d=1)"
```

returns 31 results.

when i try it out to 1000, or 10000, or 100000 I get the same 31 results.

```
geo:"Intersects(LINESTRING(126.9140625 -17.644022027872722, 142.646484375 -20.46818922264095, 133.59375 -29.305561325527698, 127.0458984375 -18.62542454070125) d=10000)"
```

i get the same amount of results. Do I have my formatting right? I thought the latest version addressed this issue and I should be able to do distance via polygons and linestrings (not just circles).

Answer (score 0):

Solr doesn't yet do this out-of-the-box.  The 'd' parameter you added isn't actually parsed/observed so it has no effect.  To get what you want, you're going to need to buffer the shape by the distance.  It just so happens that the latest version of Spatial4j has what's called a native "BufferedLineString" shape, but it's not yet fully hooked-in; so there's some integration code on your part to parse it, in order to use it. Spatial4j is the shape library used by Lucene-spatial.  But even without that you can use JTS to generate the polygon of the buffering of any other shape.